# Add attachment mailto Outlook

Tags: java, email, outlook, mailto

I want to send an email from my application with the following code:

```
public static void mailto(String subject,String path) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
   String uriStr = String.format("cmd.exe /c start mailto:%s?subject=%s&attachment=%s",
            "test@test.fr",
            urlEncode(subject),
            urlEncode(path));
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(uriStr);
}

private static final String urlEncode(String str) {
    try {
        return URLEncoder.encode(str, "UTF-8").replace("+", "%20");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

The window opens normally, everything works except the attachment.I tried many method to add an attachment to the email, however I did not find solution. It is imperative that I go through the Outlook interface for sent mail.

[Result of the execution of the code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RAFx.png)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it out with a fixed path to your Outlook client executable.

```
public static void mailto(String subject,String path) throws IOException {   
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\outlook.exe /c ipm.note /m \"test@test.fr&subject="+subject+"\" /a \""+path+"\"");
}
```